# Convert Sting to DateTime in Python using Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am working on a Machine Learning model and am trying convert a string column into a Date one. I guess it has to be a Date and Time column.

To be more specific this is the Date column, after being uploaded to Azure ML Studio it automatically became a string. I have tried to use the Edit Metadata option but it is not letting me make this change. I have also tried just to amend the format of that column on the CSV file before uploading it but it is not working. I have also checked the forum and found that some people have experienced the same problem. However I tried to apply the same solution and did not work.

```
import pandas as pd

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    dataframe1.Date=pd.to_date(dataframe1.Date, error='coerce')
    return dataframe1
```

Any help is welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the format of that column on the csv file itself. I tried one the many date and time formats available and it worked. It did not work with the first one but it did with the second one.

Thank you

Ivan